# Google Chrome does not display styling from dynamically added rows but firefox does

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

I have a table where a user has the option to add a new row for data input and a minus button for removing input. What I'm trying to do is to have the minus button inside the very last cell of the table's row, but without any border.

In Firefox, it displays just fine but in Chrome, there is a border around a table cell where I have explicitly removed it via the .style attribute.

```
...
var cell2=row.insertCell(i-1);
cell2.style="background:none !important; border-style:none !important;";
var t1=document.createElement("input");
t1.type = "button";
t1.value = "-";
t1.onclick = function(){ deleteRow(this); };
cell2.appendChild(t1);
```

[Here's what it looks like in Chrome](http://i57.tinypic.com/2ufaj5x.png),
[and here it is in Firefox](http://i62.tinypic.com/2yobjph.png)

How do I get the style to display correctly in chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `border-style: hidden`.

```
border-style: none
```

would be the correct declaration.

I guess if you correct this in your script, everything should work fine in all browsers.

**UPDATE:**

I'm not very experienced with vanilla JS, but I think you should set the styles for the element differently.

Try this:

```
cell2.style.background = "none";
cell2.style.borderStyle = "none";
```

Comment: I have corrected it to use border-style:none but it's still the same in Chrome. In Firefox the border is eliminated but in Chrome it still persists. If I use !important in border-style, it makes no difference.

Comment: I have also tried style: dotted and other border styles, which all display fine in Firefox but not in Chrome. Using Chrome v33 and Firefox 27.1 (both recently updated browsers)